# Is it possible to create indexes in Mongodb for dynamic fields?

Tags: mongodb

My site has several "domains" which represent sub-sections of the site. Each "domain" has its own users with profiles, and a search page where you can search for users based on profile fields that the users fill out.

User data from the 'users' collection is structured like so:

```
{
    username: 'shawnmichaels',
    first_name: 'Shawn',
    last_name: 'Michaels',
    domains: [
        {
            name: 'domain1',
            user_fields: {
                'bio': 'Short bio related to domain 1',
                'skills': 'Pertinent skills for domain 1'
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'domain2',
            user_fields: {
                'bio': 'Short bio related to domain 2',
                'skills': 'Pertinent skills for domain 2'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So, users have field data across multiple domains. The domain names and field names are dynamic. There could potentially be hundreds of domains for a user and dozens of fields in a domain.

Is it possible to have some sort of dynamic index so that I can search for fields under 'domain1' without getting any matches in 'domain2'?

For example, if a user1 has `"skills": ["karate", "judo"]` under 'domain1', and I want to search domain2 for "karate", I don't want a match for user1.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I've answered my own question after a day of research.

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and didn't realize you can query arrays by treating them like any other keys, like so:

```
db.users.find({domains.title: 'domain1'})
// where 'domains' is an array of object each with a 'title' key
```

With this knowledge, I added a text index for each field I want to be searchable:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({
  'username': 'text',
  'first_name': 'text',
  'last_name': 'text',
  'domains.fields.bio': 'text',
  'domains.fields.skills': 'text',
  'domains.fields.title': 'text',
  'domains.fields.training': 'text'
}, {name: 'domain_search'})
```

And I structured search queries in each domain like so:

```
db.users.find({
  'domains.title': DOMAIN_NAME, 
  '$text': {'$search': SEARCH_TERM}
})
```

Comment: Warning - this is NOT proper usage of index for searching at any field. You have to create new index for each field. The compound indexes can be used only for "prefix" searching : https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-compound/#prefixes